# Handling fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when creating a date object from a date string

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I got a strange error when creating a date object.

The error is "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Simplified code that shows the issue is

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter() ;
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" ;

let startDateText:String = (data["startDate"] as AnyObject? as? String) ?? "";      

print( startDateText ) ;
let startDate:NSDate! = dateFormatter.dateFromString(startDateText) ;
print( startDate ) ;
```

The data object when printed is

```
{
    calendar = archived;
    endDate = "2016-01-25 15:15:00";
    notes = "notes and something";
    startDate = "2016-01-25 14:00:00";
    title = "First event from the command line";
}
```

Archived is a calendar object from EKEventStore

The strange part is the code works on another device.

Any ideas on how to handle and solve "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"?

Comment: you need to use HH for 24 hours format

Comment: `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSDateFormatter`'s [`dateFromString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/dateFromString:) returns an optional `NSDate`.  Your `let startDate:NSDate!` states that `startDate` will never be nil, but `dateFromString` is returning nil.

The reason why dateFromString is returning nil is because your date format string is wrong.  Try `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` as Leo suggested in the comments, and consider making `startDate` an optional `NSDate`, only unwrapping it if it is non-nil.